# Legacy C++ code base works well only compiled with VC6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

At work I inherited a big code base. Older version was compiled with VC6.0 and works fine on Windows XP and 32-bit Windows 7.  The quad core computer is specifically made for field use in a special industry.

Managed to upgrade to VC2005 and VC2013, however, the binaries produced by newer compilers yields very high CPU usage, to a point UI is not usable.

Tried a few profilers but got quite different results.  For example, one points to PostMessageA, and another points to LineTo (MFC function).

Any clue where I should look at to find the cause?

Comment: Are you sure you've covered all the issues in porting from VC 6.0 with MFC to VC 2013? That is a significant jump and a fair amount of work. You might want to pull together a checklist of the breaking changes involved to review for things that might not just be slow, but are broken because they were missed in the port.

Comment: If the UI is unusable and it's an MFC program, I would check a few things. First, I would look to see what is going on in your OnIdle processing.  Try commenting out things to see if the response improves.  Next, check your ON_COMMAND_UPDATE_UI handlers.  Try commenting them out in the message map. Yeah, your program might not work correctly all the way, but if the UI is more responsive, try uncommenting them out one by one until you find the culprit(s). Also, see why you are calling PostMessage() and LineTo() so much. It's a red flag to me that the profiler points to PostMessage.

Comment: Joe, thank you for the suggestions!
Avi's makes sense too.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was a bug fix in MFC some years back that introduced more frequent calls to update handlers. If you have a slow update handler in your code, that is very likely the culprit. Like @JoeWillcoxson said.

Answer (score -4):

I've rarely trusted profilers. One thing I do is I will repeatedly pause the debugger and see where it ends up. If it keeps ending up with a similar call stack, that's where the problem probably is.

Of course, if you have a lot of threads, you can play with freezing individual threads and pressing play/pause. Of course, if there is a lot of intra-thread dependencies, this will be difficult.

Comment: If you don't trust profilers then I suggest you try using them more. Both `perf` (on Linux) and `VTune` (on Windows) give quite accurate (and actionable) results in my experience. They do take some effort to learn to use well, but it's worth it. Even `gprof` provides useful results.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.